# Using enum as inherited struct to scope in entity framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, enums

This is usually how you construct entities, mapping the id to a int in the database

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

I started implementing a system like this for my entities:

```
public enum PersonId : int { }

public class Person
{
    public PersonId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum AddressId : int { }

public class Address
{
    public AddressId Id { get; set; }
    public PersonId PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping the enum to a int (or other struct) in the database.

This way i can scope method and code, to not mistakenly ask for a specific address with a persons int id, as a int is always a int.

As i understand, F# have something similar to this built in?

My question here is, do anyone know if this will affect performance with entity framework in any way?

Comment: It won't, using an enum instead of an integer surely won't be the bottleneck of your application, but I don't get why you'd use an enum for the ID's?

Comment: just name the properties `PersonId` and `AddressId`. you dont need enum for that. use int

Comment: Wrapping it with a enum got the benefit that you cant fetch a address with a `PersonId`, a person with a `AdressId` etc, which you can do with a regular `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the IL level, an enum is just an integer *anyway*; any decent runtime-based meta-programming library should know to go directly to the int without any intermediate conversion - and I would be amazed if EF got this wrong.

To me, however, the real problem is more a semantic one; that is not really what enums *are intended to mean*. You might additionally get problems in some serialization and UI tools (when they are looking how to represent or parse an `AddressId` with value `100124`, etc).

Personally, I wouldn't do this. Mixing up what values mean is indeed a potential problem, but the answer to this is not abusing the type system. I "get it" that some languages offer aliases / type-defs that allow you to do this in a checked fashion, but an enum is not just a checked alias - it means more than that.

Comment: Kind of guessed the first part, and on the database it makes no difference, and serialize is a problem with MVC Json, but not Json.Net. But I understand the intention problem, it is not meant to be used in this way. But EF offers the possibility, and when doing a refactor with two new enum-ids i found five bugs due to bad code and related names.